# How to display a list of elements from a different table in a blade view?

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I have a recipe information view on a meal plan application, where users can see the specific details on how to prepare a recipe pulled from it's Recipe ID. The Recipe's ingredient information is stored in a different table, and I'm trying to pull all the ingredient names and corresponding ingredient amount with the same Recipe_ID as the current recipe that's being inspected. Recipe and Ingredients has a one-to-many relationship.

Controller:

```
 public function recipeinformation($Recipe_ID)
   {

     $datatest = Ingredients::join('mealplan_main', 'mealplan_main.Recipe_ID', '=', 'recipeingredientsmain.Recipe_ID')
     ->where('mealplan_main.recipe_id', '=', $Recipe_ID)
     ->get([ 'recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'recipeingredientsmain.amount']);

      $dat = Recipe::find($Recipe_ID);


      return view('MealPlanDisplay.recipeinformation', compact('dat', 'Recipe_ID', 'datatest'));

    }
```

The View:

```
//this works
<div class="flex flex-col">
   <h3> {{$dat->recipe_name}} </h3>
 </div>

//the attempt to display the ingredientname and ingredient amount does not work
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    @foreach ($datatest as $var)
    <p> {{$var->recipeingredientsmain.amount}} </p>
    <p> {{$var->recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname}} </p>
      @endforeach
   </div>
```

The code runs but the information does not display on the view. When I remove the foreachloop, I get the error:
**Property [recipeingredientsmain] does not exist on this collection instance.**

How get this to work properly?

Comment: Try dumping the `$datatest` variable to see if it actually contains anything, or if it's just an empty collection. Add `ddd($datatest);` before the `return`.

Comment: try with  `{{$var->amount}}`   instead of  `{{$var->recipeingredientsmain.amount}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your blade use below code by removing table name `recipeingredientsmain`

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
    @foreach ($datatest as $var)
        <p> {{$var->amount}} </p>
        <p> {{$var->ingredientname}} </p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```